# Web Search on Web browsers

Tags: search, browser, resultset

I have done a search on different browsers on google ,but they return different set of results?? Is this because of the web history or some other reason??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All Google searches depends of several parameters, to offer to the user the best answers possibles.

Various parameters can influence the returned query :
 - if you're logged in or not (see the top bar)
 - if your browser can store your search preferences (chrome is very well aware of your interrested are !) but IE if very poor to send data to Google search engine

These 2 parameters are the main that can influence differencies between the results. I've never heard of sending the history of the visited pages directly

Comment: *but IE if very poor to send data to Google search engine*  return hello

Comment: Your answer was helpful but,I do not agree with your statement * IE is very poor to send data to Google search engine* ,this is because if you compare the time that chrome and IE takes to return data from same query IE is nearby "2-3 ms" faster than chrome.